# Emgu.CV - C# - Mat data is getting corrupted

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am making a program in  windows.forms, that is controling TV, taking screenshots of the screen and measuring time for certain events to happen (menu load, video start...). I make each measurement several times in a loop before I move to the next loop. For that I am using Emgu.CV. The screenshots are stored as a Mat in my class Shot:

```
internal class Shot
    {
        public Mat image { get; }
        public int time { get; }

        public Shot(Bitmap image, Rectangle rect, int time)
        {
            Rectangle translatedRect = new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width - rect.X, rect.Height - rect.Y);
            this.image = new Mat(image.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Mat, translatedRect);
            this.time = time;
        }
        private Shot(Mat image, int time)
        {
            this.image = image;
            this.time = time;
        }
        public Shot Clone()
        {
            return new Shot(image.Clone(), time);
        }
    }
```

The rest of the Mats are only stored in the current loop as a needle.

Now the problem - every now and then (and I mean quite frequently) I am getting "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'" once I try to access the data of a Mat. The most extreme occurencce of this was when it iccured in this way.

```
var currentBlackScreen = imageProcessor.GetPrintscreenMat(chosenScreen, zone);
.
//I make some measurements here using the needle
.
currentBlackScreen.Save("000needletaken1.png"); //I successfuly tried to save the needle
.
//I am not using the currentBlackScreen in any way in this part of the code
.
currentBlackScreen.Save("000needletaken2.png"); //I get the error here.
```

I use Save() because it is a good indicator, that the Mat is corrupted. This problem seems to have started after I started using Mat(Mat, Rectangle). Can anyone please help me?

Note that I am currently leaving all the work of disposing of the images and Mats to Garbage Collector - and it have worked ok so far.
I even tried to not use the needle itself, but Clone() it every time I pass it into a function as the first thing I do.

**Edit:**
I am using winforms only to create a user interface so that the user can set up details of how the program will behave. After that winforms is not used until the end of the measurement.

Comment: Copy the rect instead of using the data directly, is my guess.  Could also be related to the way winforms callbacks works on events.

Comment: @Pete If I understand correctly what you ment, you were right. On this line:
this.image = new Mat(image.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Mat, translatedRect);
You are creating a shallow copy of the rectangle. The problem seems to have been solved by using clone() on the result:
this.image = new Mat(image.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Mat, translatedRect).clone();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved by adding clone() to the result Mat

`this.image = new Mat(image.ToImage<Bgr, byte>().Mat, translatedRect).clone();`
as @Pete suggested.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out, my comment was pretty vague.